# Update to 11.10 without touching the kernel?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, upgrade, kernel

There is some method to upgrade my Ubuntu 11.04 without touching the kernel?, is that branch 3.x kernel gives me problems bluetooth makes my system freeze, and with the current kernel (2.6.38-13) is luxury all my hardware.

I write from the google translator because my English is poor

Comment: Chances are you will break you system. That said, I use kernel 3.2.4-030204-generic-pae on Natty but had to tweak some in order to get it there.

Comment: as you get it???

Comment: What does that mean? Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wrote it, I write with the help of google translator, is a question, that I was curious about the kernel 3.2 in natty

Comment: what do you want to know

Comment: how to use the kernel 3.2 in natty?

Comment: start with https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still upgrade to 11.10 or whatever one u want and install an old kernel image.
Old images can be found [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). Just look for the version you are using then install it.

Note, you should download a total of 3 packages in each case.
Then from terminal run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: good idea!, although he knew her, would not come to that, but I will try, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible to update all the system without updating the Kernel because of the dependecies... but it this can help, The 3.x kernel series only appear in the Ubuntu 12.04 not in the 11.10.

Hope this helped ^_^

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 uses the kernel 3.0, that's my problem